Getting late initialization error in flutter open_file package
I am trying to read docx/xlsx file in flutter using open_file package. Running the flutter application in Debian 12.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

class WordViewerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String filePath;

  WordViewerPage({required this.filePath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<OpenResult>(
      future: OpenFile.open(filePath),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<OpenResult> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('Error occurred: ${snapshot.error}'); // Log the error
          return Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"));
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // Check if the file opened successfully
          if (snapshot.data?.type == ResultType.done) {
            return const SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text("File opened successfully!"),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
                child: Text("Could not open file: ${snapshot.data?.message}"));
          }
        }
        return const Center(child: Text("Unexpected state."));
      },
    );
  }
}


here is my full code.
This is the error message

flutter: Error occurred: LateInitializationError: Field '_instance@1198239922' has not been initialized.


Update the package open_file to 3.5.9, you experiment a bug in this package.
See: https://pub.dev/packages/open_file/changelog
and https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/issues/303

On Linux, the open_file package relies on external utilities such as xdg-open to open files. You can try running the following command to check if xdg-open works:
xdg-open <file_path>

You can modify the FutureBuilder to catch this specific error and handle it more gracefully.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

class WordViewerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String filePath;

  WordViewerPage({required this.filePath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<OpenResult>(
      future: _tryOpenFile(filePath),  // Wrap the future in a helper function
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<OpenResult> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('Error occurred: ${snapshot.error}'); // Log the error
          return Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"));
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // Check if the file opened successfully
          if (snapshot.data?.type == ResultType.done) {
            return const SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text("File opened successfully!"),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
                child: Text("Could not open file: ${snapshot.data?.message}"));
          }
        }
        return const Center(child: Text("Unexpected state."));
      },
    );
  }

  // A helper function to catch and handle LateInitializationError
  Future<OpenResult> _tryOpenFile(String filePath) async {
    try {
      return await OpenFile.open(filePath);
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle LateInitializationError or other errors
      print('Error while trying to open file: $e');
      return OpenResult(type: ResultType.error, message: e.toString());
    }
  }
}

If the issue persists, make sure to update your Flutter environment, dependencies, and especially the open_file package. Also, double-check that you are using a platform (Debian 12 in your case) where the open_file package is fully supported and has the required external utilities (xdg-open or similar).
